# Java-Saving a url parameter to use after a page reload

Tags: java, servlets, action, javabeans

I have a custom url that a user uses to reset their password.  The url has one parameter

```
http://localhost:8085/PlanIt/content/resetPassword.jsp?uuid=12085de1-2422-4e7c-9b62-66380d3811a9
```

When the page loads it runs a Java method which uses a

```
request.getParameter("uuid")
```

to get the value of the uuid.  After the user resets their password they click save which reloads the page but this time request.getParameter("uuid") returns null.  I tried to save the value of uuid in a variable and then when the page reloads it doesnt effect the value but it sets the variable to null.

```
ForgotPasswordBean bean = (ForgotPasswordBean) request.getAttribute("forgotPasswordBean");
    bean.setUuid(request.getParameter("uuid"));
    if (verify(request)) {
        System.out.println(bean.getUuid());
        ActionBean actionBean = (ActionBean) request
                .getAttribute("actions");
        String action = actionBean.getAction();
        ChangePasswordBean changePasswordBean = (ChangePasswordBean) request
                .getAttribute("changePasswordBean");
        ResetPasswordDAO resetDAO = new ResetPasswordDAO();

        if (action.equals("save")) {
            bean.setUuid(RequestUtil.getParameter(request, "uuidValue"));
            String planner = resetDAO.select(bean.getUuid());
```

How do I save the parameter so when the user clicks save the original value is returned and not null?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to copy the variable into a hidden form input field, 
e.g. if JSP:
`<input type=hidden name="uuid" value="<%=request.getParameter("uuid")%>">`

Can do this purely in JavaScript as well